# Minor error when trying to uninstall home-brew on Mac Apple Silicon M1 chip

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, apple-silicon, apple-m1

Im fairly new to coding and stack overflow so let me know if I do anything wrong. Basically I am following the Odin Project course and Im on the page for installing git onto my Mac. However the issue is that the command line provided to install git was actually for intel based computers and not for Apple Silicon. Im new to this stuff and was not aware of what would happen if I did install it but did not think anything would go wrong. I was so confused but still just trusted the process and went ahead and copied the default install command line into my terminal. Everything was going fine until I got this message:

```
Already up-to-date.
Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
==> Installation successful!
```

Didn't really think much of it so till I started to actually try to use it, I typed in $brew and nothing really happened and kept saying how there's no command with it. I started to panic and realise how big of a mistake I've made and now I've installed something on my laptop that I am clueless about. I did follow some other stack overflow questions and typed in some other commands. But I did this command:`echo $PATH` and somehow the brew command worked.

I went ahead and gave up so checked how uninstall it and typed the normal command to install but changed the end next to .sh to uninstall. This is what I got

```
    rmdir: /opt/homebrew: Directory not empty
Warning: Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo rmdir /opt/homebrew
Warning: Homebrew partially uninstalled (but there were steps that failed)!
To finish uninstalling rerun this script with `sudo`.
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/opt/homebrew/SECURITY.md
/opt/homebrew/etc/
/opt/homebrew/share/
/opt/homebrew/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

Now this is where I am confused. How the hell do I completely wipe this thing off my system. Someone please provide an answer I would be so happy and this time will do it correctly with my Apple Silicon system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to be panic. Homebrew is well supported in apple silicon as of now (I am homebrew maintainer myself).

Based on my reading, what you need to do is to run `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`, this would put your brew command back in place for the terminal. If you want to use it for the following terminal sessions, you can do something like `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile`. (If you are interested, you can learn a bit about basic macos terminal stuff)

Besides, you can always run `brew doctor`, it would help you on finding out the right usage of homebrew.

If you still prefer to wipe out the homebrew installation. You can try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223).

Comment: Hey there, I think wiping out the entire home-brew installation and starting from a blank slate is something I prefer. I hope that isn't a problem or dumb. I am kind of stuck on uninstalling.

Comment: Literally feel so lost, I hope I'm not offending anyone but I really am lost in terms of this, I will get better at it at some point.

Comment: the gist would help wipe out the entire installation.

Comment: I think my problems are solved now, pretty much had to have the path for my Mac on opt/homebrew/bin/brew instead of usr/bin

Comment: I have one question though, when I typed in $which -a git, I get shown two paths: /opt/homebrew/bin/git (correct one) and /usr/bin/git (not necessary I think) let me know if I shouldn't worry about this or anything like that as I am not able to move to trash anything like this and would like to stay away from doing anything like this again.

Comment: I think it is fine to keep two installations, you can always check `ls -al $(which git)` to show what is the real one.

Comment: But you do want to `rm` which is fine too, you can always `brew install git` or `xx install git` to fix the missing git issue

Comment: Its all good now and I am setup, kind of regret installing some things especially without doing research as I am quite a picky person with what goes in my system lol. Regardless, I am really happy for your response and kind of glad that my first question went smoothly. The community is actually so mature and kind (came from a toxic gaming community before quitting in August 2020)

Comment: feel free to use https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions if your question does not get enough attentions in here. :) Glad I am helpful.